# How to map urls like urls 'day and name' in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, routes

I need to validate url's for my blog. I need allow only main url sites, for example:

`https://www.example.com/2019/02/11/post_title/`

How can I route it in Laravel?

I want to do something like this:

```
Route::get('{slug}', function(){
    $post = \App\Post::where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail(); 
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a starting point for you

```
Route::get('/{year}/{month}/{day}/{title}', function ($year, $month, $day, $title) {

    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/m/d', $year . '/' . $month . '/' . $day);
    $date_errors = DateTime::getLastErrors();
    if ($date_errors['warning_count'] || $date_errors['error_count']) {
        dd('invalid date');
    }

    // do stuff
    dd($year, $month, $day, $date_errors, $date);
})->where(['year' => '^(19|20)\d{2}$', 'month' => '^(0?[1-9]|1[012])$', 'day' => '^[0-9]*$']);
```

If the year doesn't match the Reg expression (from 1900 to 2099) and for months 1 to 12, it will be 404 error

Answer (score -1):

I would do like: (pardon my bad regex)

```php
Route::get('/{date}/{title}', 'Controller@method')
->where('date', '[a-Z]+\/+[a-Z]+\/+[a-Z]')
```

then in Controller:

```php
method ($date, $title) {
  $date = Carbon\Carbon::parseFromFormat('Y/m/d', $date);
...
```